# Pointing to StackNavigator from TabNavigator throws Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-native-paper

In my React Native app, I'm using `react-navigation` version 5 along with `react-native-paper`.

I'm trying to have one of the items in my bottom tab to point to a stack navigator. When I do that, I get the following error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls
> setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a
> dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

If I point the tab item to a regular screen, everything works fine. As per the `react-navigation` documentation, I use the `BottomNavigation` component from `react-paper` as opposed to using their tab solution -- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/#using-with-react-native-paper-optional

Here's my tabs component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-paper';

// Components
import CodeScanner from '../../../screens/vendors/CodeScannerScreen';
import Home from '../../../screens/home/HomeScreen';
import Vendors from '../vendors/VendorsStack';

// Stylesheet
import { styles } from './style-home-tabs';

const HomeTabs = (props) => {

   const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
   
   // Routes
   const homeRoute = () => <Home />;
   const vendorsRoute = () => <Vendors />;
   const scanRoute = () => <CodeScanner />;
   const [routes] = React.useState([
      { key: 'home', title: 'Home', icon: 'newspaper-variant-multiple' },
      { key: 'vendors', title: 'Vendors', icon: 'storefront' },
      { key: 'codescanner', title: 'Scan', icon: 'qrcode-scan' }
   ]);

   const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
      home: homeRoute,
      vendors: vendorsRoute,
      codescanner: scanRoute
   });

   return (
      <BottomNavigation
         navigationState={{ index, routes }}
         onIndexChange={setIndex}
         renderScene={renderScene}
         labeled={false} />
   );
}

export default HomeTabs;
```

And here's the stack navigator that I'm pointing to which causes the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Components
import VendorsScreen from '../../../screens/vendors/VendorsScreen';

// Navigator
const VendorStack = new createStackNavigator();

const VendorsStack = (props) => {
   return(
      <VendorStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
         <VendorStack.Screen name="Vendors" component={VendorsScreen} />
      </VendorStack.Navigator>
   );
}

export default VendorsStack;
```

As I said, if I were to point to a regular screen, everything works fine. Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the route declarations outside the component fixed the issue. Every time the component got mounted, it was calling these functions and that was causing the issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-paper';

// Components
import CodeScanner from '../../../screens/vendors/CodeScannerScreen';
import Home from '../../../screens/home/HomeScreen';
import Vendors from '../vendors/VendorsStack';

// Stylesheet
import { styles } from './style-home-tabs';
   
// Routes
const homeRoute = () => <Home />;
const vendorsRoute = () => <Vendors />;
const scanRoute = () => <CodeScanner />;

const HomeTabs = (props) => {

   const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
   
   const [routes] = React.useState([
      { key: 'home', title: 'Home', icon: 'newspaper-variant-multiple' },
      { key: 'vendors', title: 'Vendors', icon: 'storefront' },
      { key: 'codescanner', title: 'Scan', icon: 'qrcode-scan' }
   ]);
   
   const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
      home: homeRoute,
      vendors: vendorsRoute,
      codescanner: scanRoute
   });

   return (
      <BottomNavigation
         navigationState={{ index, routes }}
         onIndexChange={setIndex}
         renderScene={renderScene}
         labeled={false} />
   );
}

export default HomeTabs;
```